# Using Hadoop in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, installation

So I just installed Hadoop using homebrew (brew install hadoop), and I'm trying to use the Java API (http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop/api/index.html). When I import for example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
```

The compiler just tells me that the package does not exist. Does anyone have any idea how to get these packages to import correctly? My JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home' so I don't know what could be the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `hadoop-core*.jar` in your java class-path to `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path`. This `jar` file is present under `$HADOOP_HOME` and the exact name of the `jar` file may vary depending on the hadoop distribution and verison.